# Printer Problems after moving to 19.04

Tags: printing, canon

I have two Canon printers (one inkjet and one laser) that printed fine under 18.04 but fail to print under 19.04.  At first, both printers seemed to be automatically (and correctly) identified as available printers but when I try to print a test page, the job hangs.  While I like the 19.04 interface, I can't afford to be without printers.  If I cannot quickly resolve the printer issue with 19.04, I will be returning to 18.04 and wait and see is things work better with 20.04.

Any ideas on this issue?

Printers are MG5420 and MF8580...

Comment: Did you try to remove and re-add the printers?

Comment: Canon usually need additional drivers. Haven't you reinstalled?

Comment: The printer worked under 18.04.  I did remove and reinstall the printer but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18/19 attempts to automatically identify Canon network printers.  Any printers found show up as icons (sometimes with messages indicating a problem).  In my case, the printer was actually installed and the icon was a bit deceptive. My fix was the following:

1. From the Settings application, select devices and remove the installed Canon printer from the system.
2. Download the UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux from the Canon support website.
3. Extract the folder to a location on your system.  In my case I extracted the folder to my Download folder
4. Open a terminal session.
5. At the prompt in the terminal session, change directory to the extracted folder.
6. In this folder there should be a program named install.sh
7. At the prompt type sudo ./install.sh
8. Enter your password.
9. When the installer is finished, there should a new application to add Canon printers.  In that application, select "Add" and choose your printer from the dropdown menu.
10. Test your printer for function with a test page of some sort.

Maybe this could be made easier for Ubuntu 20.04...